# Excel Bar Graph Showing Blank Value And Its Header

Tags: excel, excel-formula, charts

I’m making a bar graph listing the amount of candidates per interview status. Ex: 1st Phase, 2 Hired,7 3rd Round, 4 etc., I have cases where some columns do not have any candidates within the current phase (Offer accepted, 0 or blank).

I made the bar graph using a range of all my headers (status) and the values (# of candidates) beneath the headers. How would I go about making my graph not display these blank values headers?

I can’t just not add the unused headers, as it is a dynamic array, pulling data from a separate table. Every time an input of a candidate and their status in the interviewing process it updates the values in my range for the bar graph.

The issue isn’t that the chart isn’t bypassing blanks but rather it is still using the header in my range when the value beneath the header is blank. Is it even possible to fix this?

[Reference Photo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0TPh5.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use name manager with the Offset function to create a dynamic range. This talks you through it
https://excelchamps.com/excel-charts/dynamic-chart-range/
He uses COUNTA, but I have done this with countif - I don't know which will be better for your situation
=OFFSET(Dropdowns!$K$17,0,0,COUNTIF(Dropdowns!$L$17:$L$21,">1")*1,1)

Comment: Hey thanks for the help but im not looking for a dynamic range. My issue is that I have a set range and sometimes only data in the middle or last columns are populated. This leaves the headers of the data that isn't populated still within the range and added to the chart. I added a photo above for more detail on my problem.

Comment: Yes but if you sort your range largest to smallest then anything which is zero will go the end of that range, and a dynamic range can count how much of the range is zero, and exclude it.

Comment: Also if you really just want to not include headers where the value is zero, you can achieve that with an IF statement that says IF(cell >0, "Title",""). This will work to not display the header, but will leave a blank space on the chart

Comment: THANK YOU SO MUCH. It worked as you described.